# Eigenvectors of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, block-matrices

I am trying to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the following block matrix $$M = \begin{bmatrix} I & A\\A^T &I\end{bmatrix}$$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. I know I must use $A$'s SVD and so I have $$M = \begin{bmatrix} I & U\Sigma V^T \\ V\Sigma U^T & I \end{bmatrix}$$ I am unsure how to proceed from here.

I was able to find a similar question ([Finding left singular vector of a block matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448322/finding-left-singular-vector-of-a-block-matrix)) but I am a little lost on the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The eigenvector problem $$\begin{pmatrix}I&A\\A^T&I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}=\lambda\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}$$ $$\implies \begin{matrix}u+Av=\lambda u\\A^Tu+v=\lambda v\end{matrix}$$ $$\implies \begin{matrix}Av=(\lambda-1)u\\A^Tu=(\lambda-1)v\end{matrix}$$ Hence $$A^TAv=(\lambda-1)^2v, \quad AA^Tu=(\lambda-1)^2u$$ But $A^TA=V\Sigma^2V^T$ and $AA^T=U\Sigma^2U^T$, so $$\Sigma^2V^Tv=(\lambda-1)^2V^Tv,\quad \Sigma^2U^Tu=(\lambda-1)^2U^Tu$$ Since the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $\Sigma^2$ are $\sigma^2$ and $e_i$, it follows that $v_i=Ve_i$, $u_i=Ue_i$ (i.e. the columns of the matrices $V$ and $U$) and $$\lambda_i=1\pm\sigma_i$$

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. I am still lost on two parts. Could you explain how $A^TAv=(\lambda-1)^2v$ and $AA^Tu=(\lambda-1)^2u$? And also how $\Sigma^2V^Tv=(\lambda-1)^2V^Tv$ and $\Sigma^2U^Tu=(\lambda-1)^2U^Tu$ imply that the eigenvectors are the columns of $V$ and $U$?

Comment: @CBBAM Compose one with the other, $A^TAv=A^T((\lambda-1)u)=(\lambda-1)A^Tu$. Secondly, we have $\Sigma^2 x=\sigma^2 x$ implies $x=e_i$ since $\Sigma^2$ is diagonal. So $V^Tv=e_i$ or $v=Ve_i$. In general, $Ve_i$ is the $i$th column of $V$ - just multiply out and you'll see.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!